# Copy file to S3 bucket from /var/tmp location of ec2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sh

I have to copy file from `/var/tmp` from an EC2 instance to an S3 bucket. I am not getting any error while executing `sh` from java code, getting success.

But not able to see file in the S3 bucket.

Tried below two commands:

```
aws s3 cp  $Temp_Path/ComapredFiles_.txt s3://bucket-name/ComapredFiles.txt

aws s3 cp  $Temp_Path/ComapredFiles_.txt s3://bucket-name

aws s3 cp  $Temp_Path/ComapredFiles_.txt s3://bucket-name/ComapredFiles.txt

aws s3 cp  $Temp_Path/ComapredFiles_.txt s3://bucket-name
```

File should get copied to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Just a quick question, and you might forget, did you enable proper access I mean IAM role to the ec2 instance, or did you set your credentials on the insance to access s3?

Comment: If it was IAM he'd get error message. Did you check, that you have the same typo in FileSystem as in code ? `ComapredFiles_`

Comment: If you run `aws s3 cp /var/tmp/ComapredFiles_.txt s3://bucket-name`, what happens? Does it then appear if you run `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`?

Comment: I am not getting any error, sh file seems executed successfully.. and then when i check s3 bucket from aws console then there is no file present

Comment: @Sanctus file system is Unix only(LF)

Comment: @Anant, i was talking about typing of word compared - `ComapredFiles_` is it also named like this on your local machine? If you copy something that doesnt exist, it will not appear on target bucket

Comment: @sanctus it is the same name. And file with the same name present at location. Also I have tried same command from AWS cli and it is working fine and placing file to S3 bucket...issue is only when we place file to /tmp folder using java code and execute the same from java code

Comment: If you only have issues calling from Java, post minimal working example of Java code then.